# Which repeated measure statistical test must I use in this case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, statistical-significance, repeated-measures

I have a set of general conditions A, B, C, D, E and F to solve a problem. Each of these conditions lead me to different number of experiments according to a parameter that i change in each general condition:

- condition A has 6 experiments
- condition B has 24 experiments
- condition C has 28 experiments
- condition D has 5 experiments
- condition E has 25 experiments
- condition F has 8 experiments

Each experiment returns a 10-dimensional vector of accuracy used in a cross-validation machine learning approach. Now I want to compare the conditions in pairs: I want to know if its better to use condition A than B, condition C than D and Condition E than F.

Which statistical test can I use in this case? My suspicion is a repeated-measure based statistical one.

Comment: I tried to use the wilcoxxon paired test in the best experiment (best mean accuracy) of each condition and compaired them in pairs: AXB, CXD and so on. Is this right?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you are trying to do or what you need help with. What is the "problem" you have to solve? What are the "conditions"? What is the "parameter"? Why does it change? What is the "10 dimensional vector of accuracy"? What is "better"? Why do you think this is "repeated measures"?

Comment: My work is about median filtering detection in images. I try to solve this in different ways, and I call these ways the 'conditions'. Condition A is solving the problem by blurring the image multiple times and calculate image quality metrics, condition B is blurring the image just one time, condition C is applying pyramid decomposition in the image and so on. Each of these techniques has parameters that I change (e.g, condition A has 24 parameters and each one yields an experiment).

Comment: In each experiment I train and test a machine learning classifier and perform 5x2 cross validation, this yields a 10-dimensional vector of accuracy for each experiment in each condition. Now I want to compare if its better to blur the image multiple times (condition A, 6 experiments and six 10-d vectors) or just one time (condition B, 24 experiments and twenty-four 10-d vectors). Is there a recommended statistical test to use in this case?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This isn't something I know about. But now maybe others will be able to answer